# How to calculate Dynamodb provisioned capacity?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-java-sdk

I have to update one column from two dynamoDB table containing 15 million and 30 million records respectively.

Average item size is 300 bytes.
Will be using DynamoDBMapperConfig.DefaultBatchWriteRetryStrategy(10), (let me know if I should change this value?)

SQS -> Lambda

SQS containing all the partition keys as messages.
Lambda having the below code with SQS trigger with concurrency set to 5 (let me know if I should change this value?)

Code:

```
final DynamoDBQueryExpression<itemSchema> expression = createDynamoDBQueryExpression(partKey);
do {
    QueryResultPage<itemSchema> queryPage = mapper.queryPage(itemSchema.class, expression);
    List<itemSchema> itemSchema =  queryPage.getResults();

    for (itemSchema record : itemSchema) {
            record.setField1("Update");
            itemSchemaTableWriteItems.add(record);

            if (itemSchemaTableWriteItems.size()==25) {
                batchWrite(itemSchemaTableWriteItems);
                itemSchemaTableWriteItems = new ArrayList<>();
            }
    }
    expression.setExclusiveStartKey(queryPage.getLastEvaluatedKey());
} while (expression.getExclusiveStartKey() != null);
```

How much write capacity to provision to update all items within 2 hrs?

Answer (score 3):

Since your items are 300 bytes on average we'll just assume they're all below 1 KB. That means you need 1 write unit for every item.

To update 45 million items in 2 hours means you need to sustain `45,000,000/(2*60*60) = 6,250` per second.

So that's a good ballpark answer. To achieve the target you'll need to make sure your load is spread well across PKs so you don't have hot partitions, and you need to make sure your client(s) can sustain at least this amount of send. I suggest short trials.

Note that if your table was provisioned low and then you raise the level higher than it's been before, it will take some time to add the capacity. A new table initially provisioned high will get that capacity right away upon creation.

Comment: but these are separate tables right? so it will be ```table 1: 30,000,000/(2*60*60) = 4,166``` per second and ```table 2: 15,000,000/(2*60*60) = 2,083``` per second and other thing to consider is its update operation so it will consume 2 WUC (delete item and put item) so ```table 1: 4,166*2=8332``` per second and ```table 2: 2,083*2=4166``` per second. Correct me if im wrong?

Comment: Currently the table is set to ondemand capacity with max peak not more the 100 WCU. Switching to provisioned and assigning the above capacity how much time will it take?

Comment: An in-place update is charged like a write of the larger of the before or after size. For you that's probably 1 write unit still. If you switch from a low-utilized On Demand table to provisioned at 6,250 writes then you'll have the all the partitions you need in 5 to 30 minutes. You said "from two" so I thought you were joining the data, but if it's "to two" then yes split the write capacity. Provision a bit above what you need if the 2 hour limit is a hard limit, and make sure to test your load client can push at that rate.

Comment: thanks for all the suggestion. Just need clarity in 2 statements. 1) "An in-place update is charged like a write of the larger of the before or after size. For you that's probably 1 write unit still." - how do I know I'm performing an in place update? I have attached the code above and im using AWS java SDK batchWrite api call. 2) "you need to make sure your client(s) can sustain at least this amount of send. I suggest short trials." - what do you mean by short trials? like sleep for some sec?

Comment: If you’re using `BatchWriteItem` then it’s not an update. Short trials means test for like 1 minute.